# Getting keyError in my code. I am written a code but in this code i am getting keyerror:1

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

Path given to the directory

```
raw = './data/complete_ms_data/'
train_raw_dir = './data/train/'
test_raw_dir = './data/test/'
```

Number of raw train images

```
num_train = 20
```

Now there is problem in given fuction:

```
def makedir(new_dir):
    if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
        os.makedirs(new_dir)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if not os.path.exists(train_raw_dir):
        makedir(train_raw_dir)
    if not os.path.exists(test_raw_dir):
        makedir(test_raw_dir)

    print('begin processing...')
    i = 0
    roots = dict()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(raw):
        roots[i] = root
        i += 1
    del roots[0]
    for i in range(0, 64):
        if i%2:
          del roots[i]
    roots = list(roots.values()) # dict --> list
    # random.Random(487).shuffle(roots) 
    img = np.zeros([31, 512, 512]) # 31
    for i, root in enumerate(sorted(roots)):
        # print(i, root)
        png_list = sorted(glob.glob(root+'/*.png'))
        # print(png_list)
        for j, path in enumerate(png_list):
            img[j, :, :] = cv2.imread(path, 0) 
        img = img.astype(np.uint8)

        if i < num_train:
            tiff.imsave(train_raw_dir + str(i) + '.tif', img)
        else:
            tiff.imsave(test_raw_dir + str(i - 20) + '.tif', img)
            scio.savemat(test_raw_dir + str(i - 20) + '.mat', {'img':img})
    print('Done')
```

I am written this code for training and testing for the data. I want to train a images
I am getting error in line 49:

```
del roots[i]
```

KeyError: 1

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is `raw`? Are you sure you have enough files? Check the content of `dict` before the second loop? Also, you could use a list and slice.

Comment: When the code reaches the line `del roots[i]`, what value do you expect `i` to have? Do you expect the dictionary to contain such a key? Why? Did you try to check that? Where the code says `for i in range(0, 64)`, how did you decide that the number should be `64`, rather than anything else? Where the code says `roots[i] = root`, did you try to check what values of `i` get used? If you want values that are sequentially numbered, why use a dict rather than a list? If you want every other item, why use a separate loop to remove items, instead of just not putting them in in the first place?

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.